# How can GKE's Istio be configured to restrict egress?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I'd like to use Istio to restrict egress out of my GKE Kubernetes cluster.

I'm attempting to [change to the blocking-by-default policy](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-control/#change-to-the-blocking-by-default-policy) by running the following command to change the global.outboundTrafficPolicy.mode option to REGISTRY_ONLY:

```
$ kubectl get configmap istio -n istio-system -o yaml | sed 's/mode: ALLOW_ANY/mode: REGISTRY_ONLY/g' | kubectl replace -n istio-system -f -
```

That works temporarily, however because GKE has installed Istio as an add-on, the setting is [quickly reconciled back](https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/overview#modifying_control_plane_settings) to `ALLOW_ANY`.

Is there any other way to apply this setting to GKE's Istio or is there some other approach I can take to accomplish the same result?

Comment: Hello Chris, did you have any luck with it?

Comment: @Igor: no, I've become reasonably certain that, due to the way GKE's managed Istio is installed as an add-on there's no way to override this (or similar) setting(s).

I've gone to installing disabling GKE's Istio add-on and installing it myself using Istio's `helm` chart.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to block by egress service.
kubectl get svc -n istio-system |grep egress & edit it as per your requirement.

Comment: Istio versions from 1.1 on (including GKE's) [no egressgateway is installed by default](https://archive.istio.io/v1.1/docs/setup/kubernetes/upgrade/notice/#traffic-management).  I can manually install one, but then I'm not sure how I could ensure that all mesh traffic flow through it?  As I understand it, with the `ALLOW_ANY` default outbound traffic policy, the pass-through, fallback route is always available?

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for the managed version of Istio on GKE, they recommend [installing your own egress controller](https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/installing#adding_gateways) to avoid having your changes rolled back due to the reconciliation mode.

Comment: The `outboundTrafficPolicy.mode = ALLOW_ANY` setting is not specific to an egress gatway, it's in the main istio ConfigMap and read by Pilot, etc.  I can manually install an egress gateway, but then I'm not sure how I could ensure that all mesh egress traffic flows through it?  As I understand it, with the `ALLOW_ANY` default outbound traffic policy, the pass-through, fallback route is always available?

Comment: I'm not sure the `sed` substitution in your command will work as the specific setting is not actually declared in the Istio ConfigMap when in GKE. By default, the managed version blocks all the outgoing traffic through Envoy, so, as far as you have the sidecar injected in the pod, it should actually block the traffic. Is this happening on pods within the mesh?

Comment: The `sed` command does work; after running the above command, Istio begins to block egress traffic for a few minutes/seconds until Kubernetes reconciles the ConfigMap it back to it's GKE-default value.

Istio (<1.1) used to use REGISTRY_ONLY by default and thus block egress traffic, but newer versions (>=1.1) have [changed their default to ALLOW_ANY](https://archive.istio.io/v1.1/docs/setup/kubernetes/upgrade/notice/#traffic-management) and therefore allow egress traffic through `envoy` (aka the istio-proxy sidecars).